# Does the Arduino Yun have to be powered exactly at 5V?

Tags: voltage-level, arduino-yun

I'm working on a senior project and I am using a ATX PSU to supply power to the Arduino Yun and other components. If I'm not mistaken, its powered through the usb. I took a usb cord, strip the sheath and put the proper connections on the breadboard and connected the red wire from the PSU to the breadboard as well. When I measure it, the voltage is 5.1V max. I'm scared to hook it up to the Arduino since I read that if its above 5, it will fry it. Is this voltage fine? If not, will I have to put resistors on it to get it down?

Comment: The physicist in me has to mention that the words *measure* and *exactly* cannot be used together. Your measurement of 5.1V will have an uncertainty (unfortunately often mis-called "error") of `+/- x%`, so the real value is in a range. The `x%` is indicated on the measurement device and the range must be matched (worst case) with the data sheet of the component. As a further side note, the `+/- x%` may actually be `+x%, -y%` (the uncertainty is different depending on the direction) and can even be a function (in each case), where the uncertainty depends on the measured value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fine. That is only 2% too high. The microcontroller is the ATmega32U4 and it can have 5.5V. The wifi module runs at 3.3V, and it has a voltage regulator. Some voltage is also lost in the cable. If the voltage is 6V, then you are in the danger zone, but not with 5.1V.

There are clones and shields of the Arduino Yún. Each has its own power supply demands. You should read what the specifications are for your board. The official Yún board requires 5V from the USB cable or 5V at the VIN pin.

Comment: The official USB voltage tolerance is 4.75-5.25, so 5.1 is within usb tolerance, thus I would expect a device that can be powered from USB to be just fine

Comment: You was right about the voltage being loss in the cable, once I hook it up to my arduino, the voltage dropped to 5.070V, which made me feel better.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid directly powering any micro without voltage regulation. Things like zener diodes and dedicated regulators adds complexity. But you can pretty much power it off any positive rail at or above 5v DC.(Use nothing greater than the specs) They can also be had and implemented for very little, that and they are used on the UNO board.

Comment: You said “you can pretty much power it of any positive rail at or above 5v DC.“ Power what? An Arduino? (NO!) A regulator? It depends on the type of regulator. Linear regulators need a higher input voltage than their output voltage. Buck/boost power supplies are a lot more flexible. I’d be careful about making unclear statements like that, lest a naive reader feed 12V into VIN on his Arduino and fry the board and everything connected to it.